# Using pointer after free() in C99?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

My professor showed the following code:

```
void *p1=malloc(1024);
free(p1);
void *p2=malloc(1024);
if (p1==p2)
{
    printf("Now What?")
}
```

and he said it's unsafe, but why?

I know we shouldn't try access memory which was freed. However, it's OK to know where the pointer is pointing since it's just a normal pointer, as long as we don't try to read from where it's pointing to.

Comment: You shouldn't try to read from the pointer location in either case, since the memory content is indeterminate in the above code. But if `p1` and `p2` have the same value, it won't matter which one you use.

Comment: This code snippet does not contain any undefined behavior, because it doesn't access the memory at the address stored in `p1`. If `p2` has the same value as `p1`, you could even access the memory. It depends on the implementation if `malloc` will return the address of the memory just `free`d before.

Comment: Per http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4p2 - *"The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when the object it points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime."* So using the indeterminate value for program flow control is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @Bodo Your comment, yet much upvoted is incorrect. See the posted answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is in fact unsafe because a pointer to freed memory is indeterminate.

Annex J.2 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), which gives examples of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), includes the following:

> - The value of a pointer to an object whose lifetime has ended is used (6.2.4).
>
> ...
>
> - The  value  of  a  pointer  that  refers  to  space  deallocated  by  a  call  to  the `free` or
>   `realloc` function is used (7.22.3).

Where section 7.22.3p1 regarding memory management functions states:

> ... The lifetime of an allocated object extends from the allocation
> until the deallocation ...

And section 6.2.4p2 which defines the lifetime of an object states:

> The *lifetime* of  an  object  is  the  portion  of  program
> execution  during  which  storage  is guaranteed  to  be  reserved
> for  it. An  object  exists,  has  a  constant  address, and  retains
> its  last-stored  value  throughout  its  lifetime. If  an  object  is
> referred  to  outside  of  its lifetime, the behavior is undefined.
> **The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when the object it points
> to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime.**

Answer (score 0):

The above code behavior will be undefined because the pointed object is destroyed by the free function. The standard already mentioned it in their draft.

"If a pointer value is used in an **evaluation** after the object the pointer points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime, the behavior is undefined."

They also describe that the representation of a pointer object becomes **indeterminate** when the object the pointer points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime".