# Best practices followed to check availability of dangling pointers in our C projects?

Tags: c

Kindly let me know the common best practices followed in every huge C projects to check for the dangling pointers

Comment: The best practice is to write clean maintainable code so they can be avoided. Checking afterwards is quite hard, but Valgrind might help.

Comment: Some C libraries in debug mode write a special pattern into freed memory that might help to find dangling pointers...

Comment: Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69486161/using-pointer-after-free-in-c99

Comment: @Andrew Henle, I don't follow?

Comment: @ikegami Using a pointer in any way after it's freed [is UB](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4p2): "The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when the object it points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime."  So in strictly-conforming C, you can't even safely check the value of a pointer after it's been freed. Tools like Valgrind rely on platform-specific extensions and/or implementation details, and the OP didn't specify any particular platform.

Comment: Are you claiming the compiler can't use its own tools to detect undefined behaviour...

Answer (score 4):

You can find many invalid accesses by testing with a build compiled with `-fsanitize=address`, or testing when running under `valgrind`.